# Event listener on mousedown AND mouseover works but gets bugged and starts firing when conditions are not met

Tags: javascript

I'm making an Etch-a-Sketch project and I want my grid to be filled with color on mouseover only if mousedown is true. My code seems to work, but if I keep drawing, it bugs and starts drawing even after mouseup. I can't figure out where the problem is in my code:

```
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style media="screen">

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='cont' style="height: 600px; width: 600px; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  </div>
  <script src="script.js">

  </script>
</body>

</html>


JS:
const container = document.getElementById('cont');
const contSize = 600; //size of container in pixels
let size = 16; //number of columns and rows
let mouseDown = false;

generateGrid();

function generateGrid() {
  for (i = 0; i < (size * size); i++) {
    const createDiv = document.createElement('div');
    createDiv.style.width = contSize / size + 'px';
    createDiv.style.height = contSize / size + 'px';
    createDiv.className = 'cell';
    container.appendChild(createDiv);
  }
}

document.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  if (mouseDown) {
    if (e.target.className === 'cell') {
      e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
    }
  }
})

window.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  mouseDown = true;
})
window.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  mouseDown = false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need more events to set "mouseDown" to false.

Consider what happens if the user clicks and holds, moves the mouse outside, then releases. The mouseup won't be called, and "mouseDown" will be `true` even though the mouse is released.

Maybe this will help?

```
window.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
    mouseDown = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem - I just needed to add style 'user-select:none' to my page or container to avoid selecting and dragging the content.